# What are some advance concepts with Velocity?

Tags: java, velocity

I am looking at the documentation of velocity, and it seems very straightforward.

i.e. something that one can pickup in 2 hours

Am I missing something?

What are the more advanced concepts with Velocity?

Any major quirks?

Comment: That's a rather odd question.... why do you think there might be more to it?

Comment: You have to swallow the blue pill.

Comment: @skaffman applying for a job, and they want to know my proficiency with Velocity.  If it is so easy to pickup, why ask?

Comment: it's easy to pick up, but a bit quirky. Nothing fancy about it, although there is en extension mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Velocity is open source. If you want to know more about it than what the doc explains, you need to read its source or the source of things that use it. Or the many other velocity-related questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think (at least for myself) there's a  difference between "reading" about something and "using" that thing :).

Apache Velocity however is  really that easy (and despite it's limitations) the main reason it's used in so many projects, e.g. where even non-programmers need to edit/modify template code.

If you have a smart editor with support for Velocity, than writing those templates is even easier and faster :).